# Add a callback to Firebase Login Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am fairly new to React and the use of Firebase. Right now I have a Firebase.js file where I have stored and exported all of my functions and consts. This is what it looks like:

```
export const auth = firebase.auth();

export function performLogin(email, password) {
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(data) {
    //Works
  }).catch(function(error) {
    //Does not work
  });
}
```

So, I have this login.js that I am calling performLogin from, and I was wondering what would be the best way of doing this? How can I create a callback, or at least read any kind of return message? This is how I call performLogin:

```
clickLogin(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    performLogin(this.state.email, this.state.password);
}
```

And this works, as the console output tells me if the login was successful or not. However, I want to be able to use this function in order to retrieve the login status, and then determine wether or not I should prompt an error message or push the user to the admin dashboard. How would I do this?

Is it possible to call performLogin like this?

```
performLogin(this.state.email,this.state.password,(callback)){
 if (callback == true) { //Success } else { //Error }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your performLogin function could take a third parameter, a callback function that lives where your `clickLogin()` method lives:

```
export function performLogin(email, password, callback) {
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(data) {
    //Works
    callback(data);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    //Does not work
    callback({ error });
  });
}

loginResult(result) {
    if(result.error) {
        //failed
    } else {
        //logged in
    }
}

clickLogin(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    performLogin(this.state.email, this.state.password, this.loginResult);
}
```

Or you could return the promise that `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` returns and handle it in the component.

```
export function performLogin(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}

clickLogin(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    performLogin(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .then(result => //logged in)
        .catch(error => //failed)
};
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Just noticed this now, but if login with the correct credentials - the code works. However, if I have wrong credentials - the console outputs this:[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (HTTP/2.0 400) (verifyPassword, line 0). https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=APIKEYIWASGIVEN - what can be the problem here?

Comment: This is my loginResult:

 loginResult(result) {
    if(result.error) {
        //console.log(result);
        this.createNotification('error')
        
    } else {
        this.props.history.push('/admin/velkommen');
        //logged in
        //console.log(result);
    }
} 

and this is my performLogin:

export function performLogin(email, password, callback) {
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(data) {
    callback(data);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    callback({ error });
  });
}

Comment: so the notification from `createNotification()` call is not being displayed?

Comment: that's right. The same error occurs even without the createNotification() method.

Comment: you will get a HTTP 400 with a bad login with firebase - I just tested with my own app

Comment: I see. This is extremely strange. The notification triggers on onClick button events, and through regular methods, but it doesn't seem to trigger in my catch block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164883/discussion-between-tony-and-askaale).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the function onAuthStateChanged from "firebase/auth" package.

Here is a link to the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).